# {pgf-umlsd} size and width

Tags: scaling, pgf-umlsd

I'm doing a good progress learning latex. However, I'm stuck with a problem. I'm unable to change the dimensions of the sequence diagram with code below: I have used `\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}` package. Also, when I tried using `\centering` it has no affect. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\begin{sequencediagram}
 \newthread{customer}{:Customer}
  \newinst[1]{merchant}{:Merchant}
   \newinst[1]{ds}{Directory Server}
    \newinst[1]{acs}{:ACS}

     \begin{call}{customer}{Pay}{merchant}{Accept}
     \begin{call}{merchant}{rule=auth}{merchant}{activate3ds()}\end{call}
     \begin{call}{merchant}{3DS Versioning}{ds}{Invoke ID Call}\end{call}
     \begin{sdblock}{tunnel}{Device Fingerprint}
     \begin{mess}{customer}{connect ACS}{acs}\end{mess}
     \begin{call}{acs}{Request Device Information}{customer}
     {deviceInfo()}\end{call}
     \end{sdblock}
     \begin{call}{merchant}{AuthReq}{ds}{AuthResp}
    \begin{call}{ds}{AuthReq}{acs}{AuthResp}\end{call}
    \end{call}
    \end{call}
    \end{sequencediagram}
```

Answer (score 3):

`pgf-umlsd` uses a macro `\unitfactor` to set the vertical spacing in the diagram. The default value is 0.6.  You can redefine that macro inside the `sequencediagram` environment.

Another option is to use `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={transform shape,scale=<scalefactor>}}` before the `sequencediagram`. It is best to do it inside a group, so that it only applies to on diagram. In the example below, the `center` environment forms a group, and hence keeps that setting local.

As for the your comment on `\centering`, it is impossible to say why that wouldn't work, if you don't show the way you've used it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd} 
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{sequencediagram}
  % the default unitfactor is 0.6
  % adjust up or down to change y-scale
  \renewcommand\unitfactor{0.6}
  \newthread{customer}{:Customer}
  \newinst[1]{merchant}{:Merchant}
  \newinst[1]{ds}{Directory Server}
  \newinst[1]{acs}{:ACS}

  \begin{call}{customer}{Pay}{merchant}{Accept}
     \begin{call}{merchant}{rule=auth}{merchant}{activate3ds()}\end{call}
     \begin{call}{merchant}{3DS Versioning}{ds}{Invoke ID Call}\end{call}
     \begin{sdblock}{tunnel}{Device Fingerprint}
       \begin{mess}{customer}{connect ACS}{acs}\end{mess}
       \begin{call}{acs}{Request Device Information}{customer}{deviceInfo()}\end{call}
     \end{sdblock}
     \begin{call}{merchant}{AuthReq}{ds}{AuthResp}
       \begin{call}{ds}{AuthReq}{acs}{AuthResp}\end{call}
     \end{call}
  \end{call}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\tikzset{
  % add this style to all tikzpicture environments
  every picture/.append style={
    % enable scaling of nodes
    transform shape,
    % set scale factor
    scale=1
  }
}
\begin{sequencediagram}
  \newthread{customer}{:Customer}
  \newinst[1]{merchant}{:Merchant}
  \newinst[1]{ds}{Directory Server}
  \newinst[1]{acs}{:ACS}

  \begin{call}{customer}{Pay}{merchant}{Accept}
     \begin{call}{merchant}{rule=auth}{merchant}{activate3ds()}\end{call}
     \begin{call}{merchant}{3DS Versioning}{ds}{Invoke ID Call}\end{call}
     \begin{sdblock}{tunnel}{Device Fingerprint}
       \begin{mess}{customer}{connect ACS}{acs}\end{mess}
       \begin{call}{acs}{Request Device Information}{customer}{deviceInfo()}\end{call}
     \end{sdblock}
     \begin{call}{merchant}{AuthReq}{ds}{AuthResp}
       \begin{call}{ds}{AuthReq}{acs}{AuthResp}\end{call}
     \end{call}
  \end{call}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Torbjorn, I'm glad to have you in my learning process of LaTex, thanks. Your solution solves my problem. One question for general learning.... Can we have different scales for each line in the sequence?

Comment: @MdAamirAli Not sure. You can reduce the font size with a `scope` environment, e.g. `\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={font=\tiny}] \begin{call}{merchant}{3DS Versioning}{ds}{Invoke ID Call} \end{call} \end{scope}`, but that's the only thing I can think of.