# pgf-umlsd increase space between entities based on label width

Tags: pgf-umlsd

How do you explicitly widen a sequence diagram created with `pgf-umlsd`, or, ideally, direct it to be as wide as required to show its labels without overlap?

Here is a very simple `standalone` document that uses `A Long Method Name` as the "call" part of a sequence diagram. Unfortunately, this overlaps with the two sequences under `Client` and `Server`.

Is it possible to direct the `sequencediagram` to be as wide as necessary to accommodate the text?

I consulted a few answers on this site and [this document](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-umlsd/pgf-umlsd-manual.pdf), which explains how to use `\postlevel` to wrap things. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390631/pgf-umlsd-size-and-width) suggests using `\unitbox`, but so far that has only adjusted the vertical spacing, it hasn't forced the diagram to become wider. The answers to [this question(https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249200) do not seem to show a way to configure the sequence diagram as a whole to adapt to the width of its labels.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{sequencediagram}
\newthread{A}{Client}{}
\newthread{B}{Server}{}
\begin{call}{A}{A Long Method Name}{B}{}
\end{call}
\end{sequencediagram}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking a little bit at the code, it doesn't at first glance look like there's a way of doing that as the package is written. A possible workaround would be to define a new macro for threads that includes another mandatory argument for an xshift of said thread. It's a bit crude, but works for this specific case.

(By the way, the bounding box is a bit wrong, as you can see if you run the example below, I haven't tried fixing that.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

% based on \newthread macro from pgf-umlsd.sty
% add fourth argument (third mandatory) that defines the xshift of a thread.
% that argument gets passed to \newinst, which has an optional
% argument that defines the shift
\newcommand{\newthreadShift}[4][gray!30]{
  \newinst[#4]{#2}{#3}
  \stepcounter{threadnum}
  \node[below of=inst\theinstnum,node distance=0.8cm] (thread\thethreadnum) {};
  \tikzstyle{threadcolor\thethreadnum}=[fill=#1]
  \tikzstyle{instcolor#2}=[fill=#1]
}


\begin{document}
\begin{sequencediagram}
\newthread{A}{Client}
\newthreadShift{B}{Server}{4cm}
\begin{call}{A}{A Long Method Name}{B}{}
\end{call}
\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```